# What happened to the chat-feature module on the Questions page?

Tags: feature-request, design

When I enter Ask Ubuntu by http://askubuntu.com a **chat-feature module** displaying a nice  box where I can see who is on chat and where I can enter the room is displayed:

[image]

However when loading https://askubuntu.com/questions the chat-feature module is no longer present:

[image]

It is still there on http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions.

Was this feature deliberately disabled for good reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a recent change to the sidebar on individual question pages (as [written up here](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/403/why-is-the-right-column-the-way-it-is)) :

> For questions with …
>
> - 0 answers, we display only related questions
> - 1-3 answers, 40% chance of meta house ad, 40% chance of se 2.0 network ad, 20% chance of chat ad.
> - 4 answers, we display meta + house ad + chat

Apparently, the `/questions` sidebar was changed at the same time to use similar logic—no answers are shown, so no widgets appear in the sidebar.

We're reviewing that choice now to make sure that that was the right decision. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: It would be nice to get it back in the sidebar on *all* pages with sidebars. What's the concern that's stopping that happening? I'd argue that it has completely arrested the growth of our main chat room.